# Probability/Algebra Question Regarding Intersection/Union

Tags: probability

Consider two events $A$ and $B$ in sample space S, and suppose $P(A) = p_A$, 
$P(B) = p_B$.

(a) Find the largest number $l_1$ and the smallest number $u_1$ such that
$l_1 \leq P(A \cap B) \leq u_1$.

(b) Find the largest number $l_2$ and the smallest number $u_2$ such that
$l_2 \leq P(A \cup B) \leq u_2$.

I feel like this is quite easy, I just don't have the algebra knowledge to formulate a proper step-by-step answer to this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT - I think I have it. It is really just asking for the "domain" of the intersection and the union of the two sets. That is the range of possibilities for the union and intersection. This should occur when the two events are either mutually exclusive, or one is a subset of the other.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Here are a few ideas: $0 \le P(A\cap B) \le P(A) \le P(A \cup B) \le P(A)+P(B) = P(A \cup B) + P(A\cap B)$

Comment: This site uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is derived from $\LaTeX$, so you can use $\LaTeX$ commands to type mathematics on this site.   Typing is preferable to posting an image since images cannot be searched.